# Connect Elsa v3 to Azure AD

Tags: azure, asp.net-identity, elsa-workflows

How do you setup Azure AD authentication with Elsa v3?

In Elsa v2, we did something like this and just wrapped Elsa in a login flow:

```cs
services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/");
    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/endpoints");
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

For v3 I added this to the startup:

```cs
elsa.UseIdentity(identity =>
{
    identity.TokenOptions = options => options.SigningKey = "sufficiently-large-secret-signing-key";
    identity.UseAzureIdentityProvider(); // my custom extension below
});
```

This is what I have so far for the `UseAzureIdentityProvider()` extension method but not sure how to connect the Microsoft Identity `IUserStore<T>` and `IRoleStore<T>` to Elsa's `IUserStore` and `IRoleStore` respectively. The interfaces look straightforward enough to connect them together but getting the actual user store and identity store from Azure properly registered for injection into this custom class I created is where I am a bit lost:

```cs
public static class ElsaAzureActiveDirectoryIdentityAdapterServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void UseAzureIdentityProvider(this IdentityFeature identity)
    {
        identity.Services.AddIdentityCore<User>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddUserStore<User>()
            .AddRoleStore<Role>();

        identity.Services.AddSingleton<ElsaAzureActiveDirectoryIdentityAdapter>();
        identity.Services.AddSingleton<IRoleStore>(provider => provider.GetService<ElsaAzureActiveDirectoryIdentityAdapter>()!);
        identity.Services.AddSingleton<IUserStore>(provider => provider.GetService<ElsaAzureActiveDirectoryIdentityAdapter>()!);

        identity.UserStore = provider => provider.GetService<IUserStore>()!;
        identity.RoleStore = provider => provider.GetService<IRoleStore>()!;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Connects Elsa to Azure AD for identity authentication.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="identityRoleStore">The Microsoft Identity role store.</param>
/// <param name="identityUserStore">The Microsoft Identity user store.</param>
public class ElsaAzureActiveDirectoryIdentityAdapter(IRoleStore<Role> identityRoleStore, IUserStore<User> identityUserStore)
    : IRoleStore, IUserStore
{
    #region Role Store Methods

    public Task AddAsync(Role role, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new()) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public Task DeleteAsync(RoleFilter filter, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new()) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public Task SaveAsync(Role role, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new()) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public Task<Role?> FindAsync(RoleFilter filter, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new())
        => filter.Id != null ? identityRoleStore.FindByIdAsync(filter.Id, cancellationToken) : null;

    public Task<IEnumerable<Role>> FindManyAsync(RoleFilter filter, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new()) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    #endregion


    #region User Store Methods

    public Task SaveAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new()) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public Task DeleteAsync(UserFilter filter, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new()) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public async Task<User?> FindAsync(UserFilter filter, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new())
    {
        if (filter.Id != null)
        {
            User? user = await identityUserStore.FindByIdAsync(filter.Id!, cancellationToken);
            if (user != null)
            {
                return user;
            }
        }

        if (filter.Name != null)
        {
            User? user = await identityUserStore.FindByNameAsync(filter.Name!, cancellationToken);
            if (user != null)
            {
                return user;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

That does not currently work however:

[image: Error Message]

Does this approach seem correct? Should I be doing something different to register Azure AD with Elsa Studio v3? I am setting up the Blazor WASM client if that matters for the answer/approach.